# How to make true && false equal to true in angularjs expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, boolean-logic

I'm trying to check if an input has been touched and is empty (without the built in functions in angular).

```
<form-input is-invalid-on="isTouched && !gs.data.name || gs.data.name.length > 50"></form-input>
```

If `isTouched && !gs.data.name` evaluates to `true && false` then that side of the expression becomes `false`

So my question is quite simple, how do I make the entire expression evaluate to true if the input has been touched and if it's empty or has a length greather than 50?

Comment: `true && true` is not true in javascript? where did you read that?

Comment: Why should `true && true` become `false` just because `true == true` isn't `true`? Also, why should `true == true` not be `true` in Javascript?

Comment: You mean `isTouched && !gs.data.name.length`?

Comment: That's what I've read, and I've also checked by printing it, it says that both are true but the value is false. Which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @kazupooot It gives the same results whether you use length or not.

Comment: Sorry. Try this `isTouched && gs.data.name.length`

Comment: Add some parenthesis to make it clearer for what you are expecting the order of operations to be.

Comment: @djskinner I tried that but it yields the same result.

Comment: What about the `is-invalid-on` directive. Is it receiving the value properly. Should this directive accept a value in braces `{}`?

Comment: I've bound it with '=' in the scope object for the form-input directive, so it will evaluate whatever you pass in. And I can see that the value is being evaluated correctly because I can print the value inside the directive just fine. Problem is just that true && true becomes false.

Comment: true && true is always true! [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/79acedzv/1/)

Comment: Also what are you trying to check by this condition `isTouched && !gs.data.name`. One is boolean while other, guessing by variable name, is a name. Are you checking for `gs.data.name` existence?

Comment: @RahulSharma I figured out that it's not actually true && true but rather true && false, so it never becomes true since && takes last falsy value. Still not sure how to make it evaluate to true though.

Comment: remove the exclamation mark

Comment: But then the logic is wrong.. "if touched and has a value" rather than "if touched and is empty"

Comment: doesn't checking `gs.data.name.length > 50` mean it has a value?

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes, it can either be empty and invalid or it can be invalid once it has a value greather than 50. Everything in between is ok.

Comment: then do `isTouched && !(gs.data.name.length == 0 || gs.data.name.length > 50)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason as to why it was behaving so strange, and as this question has many answers I could not delete it. So I might as well explain what happened.

It turned out that `isTouched` was always `undefined` because I was using it outside of the directive (even if it was used in an attribute of the directive) which made the expression `undefined && false`, resulting in `isInvalidOn` always being `false`.

Instead I made it so that I used `isTouched` later in the actual `form-input` template as `ng-class={invalid: isInvalidOn && isTouched}`, resulting in the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form-input is-invalid-on="(isTouched && !gs.data.name) || (gs.data.name.length > 50)"</form-input>
```

Comment: That was used as attribute directive. You cant remove quotes

Comment: Did you tried like this? (isTouched && !gs.data.name) || (gs.data.name.length > 50)

Comment: Try with gs.data.name!=undefined

Answer (score 0):

can try using `()` and also check `gs.data` like `isTouched && (!gs.data || !gs.data.name || !gs.data.name.length  || gs.data.name.length > 50)`

```
<form-input is-invalid-on="isTouched && (!gs.data || !gs.data.name || !gs.data.name.length  || gs.data.name.length > 50)"></form-input>
```

Comment: It's an HTML attribute, not a variable. Edited to make it more clear.

Comment: Using parenthesis gives the same results I'm afraid.

Comment: using parenthesis doesn't make any difference. It just adds readability. And is always computed before OR.

Comment: Updated my answer. Can you try it now ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is used as attribute directive.

`is-invalid-on="(isTouched && gs.data.name.length) || gs.data.name.length > 50"`

Reason? I assumed your `gs.data.name` is a string. Empty string when evaluated in javascript is still a truthy value. So you must evaluate it to length.

Comment: I need to check if the input is empty, not if it's touched and has a value. Adding parenthesis still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Angular expression does not work exactly the same than javascript from what i got try this one :

```
<form-input is-invalid-on="isTouched && gs.data.name.length==0 || gs.data.name.length > 50"></form-input>
```

Assuming you properly initialized gs.data.name to empty string.

By the way you forgot the > on your tag.